# C - Memory size pointer of char

Tags: c, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to write a function to assign text input to a `char**`. Where each word is stored in a `char*`. When I was doing this I was getting errors that I think indicated that I didn't allocate enough memory so I wrote a little test program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char **input=NULL;
    char **help=NULL;
    for(int i=1;i<300;i++){
        help=realloc(input,i*(sizeof(char*)));
        if (!help)
            return 0;
        input=help;
        input[i]="test";
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Now this works just fine, but when I assign per character as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char **input=NULL;
    char **help=NULL; 
    char *help2=NULL;
    for(int i=1;i<300;i++){
        help=realloc(input,i*(sizeof(char*)));
        if (!help)
            return 0;
        input=help;
        for (int j=1;j<5;j++){
            help2=realloc(input[i-1],j);
            if (!help2)
                return 0;
            input[i-1]=help2;
            input[i-1][j-1]='t';    
        } 
    }
    return 1;
}
```

I get a segmentation fault on line 14. I think this is because the `input` does not have enough space. But since the size of a character is one and I used `sizeof(char*)` I don't see how it is not enough. How much memory would I need to allocate and why did it work in my first example? Thanks!

Comment: There is no guarantee the pointer you made room for in the initial `realloc` of the outer pointer array is actually *determinate*. Passing it to `realloc` on the *inner* loop is grounds for *undefined behavior*. In short, for `realloc(input[i-1],j)` the initial value of `input[i-1]` is indeterminate; using it there is *bad*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clang` finds the problem right away.

```
test(72707,0x7fffe32443c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fffe0051090: pointer being realloc'd was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

The problem is here.

```
help2=realloc(input[i-1],j);
```

While `input` has been allocated, none of its elements have been initialized. `realloc` will act like `malloc` if the pointer is null, but if its asked to reallocate the uninitialized garbage pointer in `input[i-1]` it will freak.

Instead you must properly initialize `input` before trying to `realloc` its elements.

A memory checking tool such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) will help find these sorts of mistakes.

Comment: Iow, after `input=help;`, put `input[i-1] = NULL;`